# Create a "wide" table recording all overlaps between polygons in PostGIS

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I have a set of overlapping polygons and would like to record which polygons are overlapping at each intersection. I have followed the instructions at:
boundlessgeo.com/2014/10/postgis-training-creating-overlays/

So I now have a set of polygons recording all the unique intersections between all the overlapping polygons (and have added the count of the number of overlaps) but I am stuck at how to indicate which polygons overlapped at that area. 
So for example if I had 26 polygons labelled a-z I'd like to end up with a table with 26 columns for each intersection showing a 1 or a 0 as to whether it was overlapping at that intersection.
 [image]

### Code used so far

***1 break up intersecting polygons**

CREATE TABLE boundariesd AS
SELECT ST_Union(ST_ExteriorRing(geom)) AS geom
FROM uniond;

***2 create unique polygons from intersections**

CREATE SEQUENCE polyseqd;
CREATE TABLE polysd AS
SELECT nextval('polyseqd') AS id, (ST_Dump(ST_Polygonize(geom))).geom AS geom
FROM boundariesd;

***3 get the count of intersecting polygons**

ALTER TABLE polysd ADD COLUMN count INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
UPDATE POLYSD set count = p.count
FROM (
  SELECT count(*) AS count, p.id AS id
  FROM polysd p 
  JOIN uniond c 
  ON ST_Contains(c.geom, ST_PointOnSurface(p.geom)) 
  GROUP BY p.id
) AS p
WHERE p.id = polysd.id;

John Barça suggested using crosstabN() which looks appropriate but still not clear to me how to implement it.

Comment: You are looking for crosstab in Postgres. However, this is going to get large really quickly, if you table is going to be n * n in the number of input polygons. You could also use array_agg, which will produce an array of intersected polygons for each input polygon-.

Comment: I wonder if it would help if you explain why you wish to do this. Maybe there's a better method for achieving the same end than one as complex as yours. What are these polygons and how many or what types of overlaps do you need to determine?

Comment: I agree with @martinf. I initially thought this was interesting, but I can't see how it would scale. If you could explain a bit more about what you are trying to achieve, it would help. A sparse matrix sounds like a better solution?